# Access assets folder's files with wildcards or regex

Tags: android, android-assets

Is there any way to access a file into *assets* folder by name with regular expression?

Only selected one file but obvious the suffix into the name

Something like:

```
    aFD =SessionManager.getAppContext().getAssets().openFd("box*.png");
```

The case:

```
      /assets/box_1223.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get all files from assets folder

```
AssetManager amgr = getAssets();
    String[] list = amgr.list("./");
    for(String s : list){
        Log.d("File:", s);
        //check if filename is what you need
        if (s.contains(what you need OR regex pattern)){
            //do staff
        }
    }
```

You can view all files and take only what you need, by using `REGEX` or `contains()`

Comment: My question was oriented if the Android API would resolve it in a transparent way.  However this response is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Just walk through the list...

```
for( String fileName : getAssets().list( "" ) ) {
    if( fileName.endsWith( ".png" ) ) {
        // here's your image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for get a file path name from assets directory by regular expresion:

```
public String getFileNameFromAssetsByExpresion(String dirFrom, String nameExp) {
AssetManager am = SessionManager.getAppContext().getAssets();
String nameRetExp = null;
try {
    for (String s : am.list(dirFrom)) {
    // check if filename is what you need
    if (Pattern.matches(nameExp, s)) { nameRetExp = s; break;}
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return nameRetExp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found you need to recurse through the assets folder if you have created directories within it.

```
private void listAssets(String startPath, int level) {
    try {
        for(String s : getAssets().list(startPath)){
            Log.d(TAG, "Level " + level + " asset found: " + s);
            if (Pattern.matches(nameExp, s)) { 
               // TODO: Handle the asset matching the regex here!
            }    

            // Recursively call ourself, one level deeper
            String newPath = s;
            if(startPath.length() > 0) {
                newPath = startPath + "/" + s;
            }
            listAssets(newPath, level + 1);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No assets for: \"" + startPath + "\"");
    }
}
```

Then I kicked this off by searching for top level assets by passing an empty string

```
listAssets("", 1);
```